# Rewrite rule to remove file extension from sub-directory

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to remove the extension of file which is in subdirectory i.e. `abc.com/subdirectory/file.html`, tried evry possible way with rewrite rule, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like

http://www.abc.com/subdir/file right?

So you can do it with .htaccess with

```
## Remove Extension ##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

I use it with php and then I simply write www.abc.com/subdire/file

**REMEBER ** I don't know if this solution suit all your needs, your question is really general. Please provide some information

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for you.

URL `'domain.com/index.html'` to display as `'domain.com/index'`

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```